# how to test slim middleware (phpunit)

Tags: unit-testing, redirect, phpunit, response, slim

I created a Middleware wich should only redirect the user to an other Website (given in Request Url by the Parameter redirect)

```
class Middleware
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        // Call next middleware or app
        $response = $next($request, $response);

        $redirectUrl = //get redirect url

        return $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Location', $redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

I already testet this and the Redirect works fine. So I came to that Point to write Unit-Tests. I failed ... This was my attempt:

```
class MiddlewareTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $request = array(...); //inserted needed properties

    public function testInvoke(String $url) {
        $next = function () : bool
        {
            return true;
        }; //empty function
        $request['request']['scriptUri'] = "/parameterStuff&redirect=" . $url; //overwrite the Uri with provided Url
        $redirect = new Middleware($request, array(), $next);

        //just to test if result of response still empty
        $iCount = count((array)$redirect);
        $this->assertEquals(0, $iCount);

    }

    public function invokeProvider() : array
    {
        return array(
            array('http://example.com')
        );
    }
}
```

This test is successful but ofc it shouldn't... The return of this function should be a valid response. I tested this in my Browser and echo the return. It has a value there and it's the correct response with the expected Header. The return Value I receive in my Unit-Test is an empty object.

I red the Slim [Documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#detect-header) about the response Object and it sais:

> This method returns a copy of the Response object that has the new header value.
>   So I should definitely receive something from it. I also tried to return a copy of the response:

```
$copyresponse = response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Location', $redirectUrl);
return $copyresponse;
```

This don't works as well. Any Idea what could cause my Problem and how to solve it?

(I want to test if the redirect url is set correctly in the response to ensure that the redirect would work)

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the request and check if the `Location` header is correctly set, its length is 1 and the status code is `200`. I wrote [some](https://github.com/DavidePastore/Slim-Validation) [different](https://github.com/DavidePastore/Slim-Config) [middleware](https://github.com/DavidePastore/Slim-Restrict-Route) and I used this method.

```
class LocationTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * PSR7 request object.
     *
     * @var Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * PSR7 response object.
     *
     * @var Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $response;

    protected $headers;

    protected $serverParams;

    protected $body;

    /**
     * Run before each test.
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $uri = Uri::createFromString('https://example.com:443/foo/bar');
        $this->headers = new Headers();
        $this->headers->set('REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1');
        $this->cookies = [];
        $env = Environment::mock();
        $this->serverParams = $env->all();
        $this->body = new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+'));
        $this->response = new Response();
        $this->request = new Request('GET', $uri, $this->headers, $this->cookies, $this->serverParams, $this->body);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider locationProvider
     */
    public function testLocation($url)
    {
        $options = array(
          'ip' => '192.*',
        );
        $mw = new RestrictRoute($options);

        $next = function ($req, $res) {
            return $res;
        };
        $uri = Uri::createFromString('https://example.com:443/foo/bar?redirect=' . $url);
        $this->request = new Request('GET', $uri, $this->headers, $this->cookies, $this->serverParams, $this->body);
        $redirect = $mw($this->request, $this->response, $next);
        $location = $redirect->getHeader('Location');
        $this->assertEquals($redirect->getStatusCode(), 200);
        $this->assertEquals(count($location), 1);
        $this->assertEquals($location[0], $url);
    }

    public function locationProvider(){
      return [
        ['http://www.google.it'],
        ['http://stackoverflow.com/'],
      ];
    }
}
```